# How can I pull/make <commit_hash> into head, when I cloned the tree with --depth=1?

Tags: git

I tried 3 different methods all of which return failures:

**First try**

`git pull origin <\hash_here>`

> error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object
>   <\hash_here>

**Second try**

`git checkout <\hash_here>`

> fatal: reference is not a tree: <\hash_here>

^ this one I quiet understand since it literally isn't in a tree

**Third and last try**

`git clone https://github.com/repo/repo.git --depth=1 -b <\hash_here>`

> warning: Could not find remote branch <\hash_here> to clone.
>
> fatal: Remote branch <\hash_here> not found in upstream origin

I'm not quiet sure how to git yet so, if someone could steer me into the right direction, and I think my google-fu is weak.

Comment: Your best bet is to drop the `--depth 1` entirely. Clone the whole repository and you have everything and the whole problem goes away.

Comment: I guess, that with kernel trees that have hundreds of thousand of commits, for those I could just increase the depth to at least how "deep"/many commits back I want to access

Comment: You can do that, but I just keep a clone handy. The occasional `git fetch` to update it adds a few thousand commits, which hardly takes any time at all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly clone the repo from the github using `git clone`

```
git clone https://github.com/repo/repo.git
```

Once git clone is done, you can create the git branch

```
git checkout -b <branchName>
```